# Broken WP images after domain move

Tags: wordpress, image, migration

I have just moved a site from the domain trfinch.com to moralesfinch.com and all the images seem to be broken. I know this is a common issue, but my problem seems particuylarly complex.

After the move, I used the 'Better Search Replace' plugin to replace all absolute links in the database. I am seeing the broken img icon in all instances, wether in the Media Library or the Front end.

However, here's the interesting bit, if I inspect the image code and manually visit the URL, the images are all there. Something is stopping them pulling through to the main site.

The issue also seems to apply to background images and favicons too.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image urls look right, it is most likely not a problem with wrong `siteurl` and `homeurl` as codenathan pointed out, but it is still a good idea to check. My instinct would say it is a problem with routing/permalinks. Try updateing the permalink structrue, or even try deactivating pretty permalinks and see if it helps.

I observed that your website forwards you to the main page (not the 404 page) when you put in the image url directly into the address bar. Do you have access to your server logs? Try locking at Apache's `access.log` to find out what happens to the `.jpg` requests.

My last guess would be a permission issue with the uploads folder, but there is no way to know without log files.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @antix. Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I'm no further forward, the siteurl and homeurl are as expected, and if they weren't surely the site wouldn't be showing at all? Updating permalinks didn't work, and the 404 page is purposely setup to redirect to the homepage, so that's not unusual.

Comment: Aha! It does indeed appear to be a permissions issue on the uploads folders. The main /uploads/ folder had permissions of 744 (fine), but all of the sub-folders had permissions of 0, meaning they were forbidden. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

you may want to open the database and look at the table called **wp_options**

and look at column labelled option_name and look for the records for : -

**siteurl** and **homeurl**, and if these records still reference the old site replace them with the new site domain.

Comment: Hi @codenathan, no luck, these are both correct. If they were wrong surely the whole site would be down?